# Who has got *a* flowerbed near *the* house?

Tags: articles

I have a question about articles. In this sentence...

> Who has got *a* flowerbed near *the* house?

Why do we use "a flowerbed" but "near the house"?

Answer (score 1):

**The** noun = that noun of which you and the speaker are aware. You may be aware of "noun" because

(i) It is the only "noun" that is present: (A and B are on a beach): "**The** beach is clean."

(ii) it has been mentioned before: **A** cat is in the tree and **the** cat is big.

(iii) the context specifies the noun: **The** book **that I wrote.** -- *that I wrote** specifies the book.

In *"Who has got a flowerbed near **the** house?"*, "Who has got a flowerbed" = Who **owns** a flowerbed - if you own a flowerbed near a house, then the implication is that the house is your house, i.e. a specific house.

(iv) noun is common knowledge; **The** moon is bright; **the** president spoke.

A/an "noun" =

(i) one example of that "noun"; "**A** cat is a good pet."

(ii) one "noun" from many nouns: "Take **an** apple from the bowl."

(iii) a "noun" whose precise identity is not important: "I saw **a** man on an elephant today.

(iv) a "noun" whose precise identity is not known: "**A** customer has stolen some milk."

In *"Who has got a flowerbed near **the** house*?", "**a**" = **one example of a** flowerbed.